# How to setup react in new project after globally install?

Tags: reactjs

I have installed my react app globally. Now I would like to create a new react project. How to set up react in my new react project? When I command NPX create-react-app my-app it not working telling react is globally installed. How to set up react in the new project after being globally installed?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already installed the `create-react-app` package globally. Now you just need to execute `create-react-app your-app-name`.

Comment: Not working telling this =bash: create-react-app: command not found

Comment: remove `create-react-app` globally by running `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`. Then try with `npx create-react-app your-app-name`